# Can't set instant app meta data tag with value 1337 and app link at the same time in manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play-console, android-sdk-tools, android-instant-apps

I'm getting below error when I upload .aab file for preparing release.

**The meta-data element 'com.google.android.gms.instant.flavor' has an attribute 'android:value' with a value of 1337 and a URL: example.com at the same time. URLs are only allowed in a base module's manifest which does not define flavor or is the default flavor.**

In order to release it as an Instant Game, we need to set the value 1337 (https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/instant-play-games-checklist # 13 of the list). If I remove the mention of deep linking from the manifest, I can upload it, but can't Instant Game and deep linking coexist?

I've tried using different flavors of manifests for the installed and instant versions, but I get the same error.

Maybe I'm not writing well, but I couldn't find a sample that worked correctly. Is there a sample code somewhere that sets both the deep link and the 1337 value?

Answer (score 0):

No, no way around it. An Instant Game can only be launched from the Try Now button, not from deep link URLs. This is unlike Instant Apps, which are *only* launched from deep links.

Comment: We had an instant app that has a deep link and we are able to successfully launch it from the url and try now button. But now we wanted it change to Instant Games.So, we have removed the deeplinks url and included that 1337 tag in the build and able to upload it in play store(internal test track). But as soon I click on try now button it is redirecting to old deep link which we had already removed from the build. Everytime I click on try now it redirects to the url. Any clue for this?

Comment: I don't know what the issue is. It sounds like a bug, distinct from the upload validation error. You're saying you were able to publish an app with both deep link and Try Now, without triggering the validation. And now you have a new version in Internal Test, where you removed the deep link (because of the validation), and the Try Now button launches the old version? Presumably the Install button launches the Internal Test version? It does sound like a bug. What's your package name, if you don't mind sharing?